# Class derived from template does not see the constructor

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I try to inherit from the class template "TControl" but the derived class "TControlML" does not see the constructor of the base class. I have read related articles but still do not see the cause. I have made a minimal example:

```
using namespace std;

class MeshLink
{
};


template<typename WU_TYPE>
class TControl
{
public:
    TControl(std::vector<WU_TYPE>& vWorkunits_):
        sTodo(vWorkunits_.begin(),vWorkunits_.end())
    {}
    std::set<WU_TYPE> sTodo;    
};



class TControlML:public TControl<MeshLink*>
{
public:

};


int main()
{
    vector<MeshLink*> vMeshLinks;
    TControl<MeshLink*> ctrl(vMeshLinks); // Good
    TControlML ctrl2(vMeshLinks); // Fails

}
```

GCC says:

```
test.cpp:35:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘TControlML::TControlML(std::vector<MeshLink*, std::allocator<MeshLink*> >&)’
  TControlML ctrl2(vMeshLinks); // Fails
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use base constructor, you might use `using` for that

```
class TControlML:public TControl<MeshLink*>
{
public:
    using TControl::TControl;
};
```

Or the old way:

```
class TControlML:public TControl<MeshLink*>
{
public:
    TControlML(std::vector<WU_TYPE>& vWorkunits_):TControl(vWorkunits_) {}
    // Same for each constructor
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
using TControl<MeshLink*)>::
```

TControl;

This is because ctors are not inherited automatically.